# Gesture detection: SelectableText inside ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-widget

I have a problem in Flutter Web with components that are `Clickable` (`ElevatedButton`, `GestureDetector`, etc) and at the same time contains a `SelectableText` widget inside.

The main problem is that a single click on top of the `SelectableText` does not trigger the `onPressed` button callback. Instead, it looks like 'initiates' a text selection.

From my point of view, text selection should only be initialized if a double tap, drag start or long tap happens on the text, but not on single tap.

A very simplified version of my problem:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('onTap');
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36),
            child: const SelectableText(
              'Select me, but I also want to be clickable!',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Note the `padding` between the `ElevatedButton` and the `SelectableText`

Any tips? ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you are trying your best to mimic the "native web experience" where all texts are selectable, and like you said, "tap and drag start are different", but their differences might be as little as 1 pixel.

If you look at this web page (stack overflow), my user name is clickable, try to drag and select it, you can't. Now scroll up, below your question, the tags are clickable, try to drag and select on the word "flutter", you can't...

So honestly, for those texts on buttons, maybe just don't let them be selectable :D

But if you insist, there's `onTap` event on `SelectableText` widget as well, so you can fire the same callback as the button, so it doesn't matter where user clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried that as well. The problem with the `SelectableText.onTap` is that it is also fired when the text selection starts.

Comment: @RobertEstivill I added more details to talk you away from doing this... also, `onTap` should not fire when text selection starts, I just tested it again (chrome, macOS, flutter 2.8), it only fires when there's no text selection.

Comment: I was wrong. `SelectableText.onTap` does work as intended and it seems this is the closest I will get to the behavior I want. One caveat is the miss fire of the `SelectableText.onTap` when double click (to select all the text) or single click to undo the current text selection. Thanks for your answer.